# Advantages of auxiliary classes when extending Active Directory schema

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema

I need to add some attributes to the user class in Active Directory.

I see that to do this it is either possible to add the attributes directly to the user class, or to create an auxiliary class containing my attributes, and then attach the auxiliary class to user.

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches? I read somewhere that using an auxiliary class is recommended, but I could not find out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an auxiliary class means that your private extensions are contained within this class and can be handled as one entity, and it is separated from the standard user class, avoiding conflicts. As this has no drawbacks and might avoid potential problems down the road, I can't think of a single reason why anyone would even consider to extend the user class instead of using an aux class.

Comment: Thanks, for sure I will go for the auxiliary class. What kind of conflicts could there be?

Comment: I can't think of a specific issue at the moment, but I know from experience that you should never alter something as ubiquitous as an AD default schema if you can avoid it,  as all kind of things expect it to be in a certain state and maybe don't work well if this state is altered in any way. These issues will pop up in places you expect them least and are usually difficult to debug.